# Android Location/GPS questions

Tags: android, gps, location

A couple of questions regarding Location which I have not found answers to:

1. `Location.getLatitude()`/`getLongitude()` return a double. What units is this double expressed in? Radians? Decimal degrees? The documentation doesn't give any indication whatsoever!
2. What should I enter using DDMS in my AVD's file system to represent a sample location (say for example 51°N, 1° 30'W) to be found by `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(GPS_PROVIDER)` and where should I put it (meaning what folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Location.getLatitude() return values in degrees for example: 51.234
2. See this http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-set-location-emulator

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can see the setting on the Eclipse DDMS tab now you have pointed it out - just needed to scroll the control window down a bit :-)